# Is there a programmer's text editor for OS X with narrowing?

Tags: macos, editor

I think the title is essentially self-explanatory except for a necessary clarification and caveat:

#### Clarification

I'm not entirely sure if 'narrowing' is the universal term for the feature I'm referring to. What I mean is something like Emacs' 'narrow buffer', ie. the ability to select a region and quickly narrow the editor window to show only that region, and then after some edits to be able to quickly zoom out to see/edit the full file again. It's a feature I like, and find far more useful than code folding.

#### Caveat

Of course the answer is 'yes -- (X)Emacs' (and possibly vim?). But I'm looking for something other than vim or Emacs; almost certainly a more GUIsh one (think Textmate, TextWrangler etc).

Comment: <del>Perhaps better suited to the programmer's stack.</del> Nevermind, they don't want it: "If your question is about programming tools, please ask on Stack Overflow instead." It's like juggling.

Comment: I'm sure Mr. Atwood will delete without prejudice if he feels the question's misplaced ...

Comment: Hah. I knew it. Why then is there still a 'tools' tag? The question is not, of course, remotely off-topic to that. Power (to close) without responsibility (to explain) always corrupts. I'd love one of the closers to try to explain how the question doesn't relate to "*software tools commonly used by programmers*" (quote on acceptable topics from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq))

Comment: I've asked this question again [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306537/is-there-a-programmers-text-editor-for-os-x-with-narrowing). Hope that's not outwith SO etiquette.

Comment: @Chris: Reasking an identical question is not the right thing to do. Instead, the right thing to do would be to reopen this one. (It has now 3 reopen votes.) You might try to edit the question to be more clearly software-developing-focused. Or raise a question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: @Paŭlo: that's fair enough. But how it's a mystery to me how one can edit a question to respond to close votes when those who voted to close don't have the simple courtesy to explain in what they had in mind.

Comment: About the terminology: a similar feature appears in outline processors, where it is called `hoisting.' I don't know of an editor that does this (although it sounds like something I'd like to try), so I've no idea if that term is used with editors.

Comment: @Michael: yes, I had forgotten the outliner cognate. Taskpaper, which could be considered a kind of outliner, does the same thing. If only XCode4  supported some kind of sensible user scripting, it would be easy enough to extract a selection into a tab or alternate editor, and push it back after edits.

Answer (score 1):

My researches seem to suggest that the straightest answer is just 'no'. I haven't been able to find an editor that runs on OS X that supports narrowing, other than emacs.

I have however figured out a workaround that might be of interest for some scenarios, which is to use Hog Bay Software's [QuickCursor](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/quickcursor) in conjunction with one or more editors.

For example, I've tried setting up QuickCursor to fire up TextMate. So now when working in XCode, I can select the text I want to narrow to, hit the global hotkey I have set up, and the selected text pops up in a TextMate window. That can be edited, then a save and dismiss window pops the edited text back in XCode.

This also works if you're just working in TextMate (or, I imagine, one of the other editors that QuickCursor can control); ie. you can select select test in the editor, trigger QuickCursor to open the selected text in a new window, and later pop that text back to the original window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is not what you want, but you didn't specifically say so:  [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org)?  It's an emacsen with good integration with OS X (cut, paste, menus, toolbars, etc).

Comment: No, you're right, not exactly what I want, but thanks for the pointer anyway. I fully accept all the claims of magnificence made for emacs and vim, and have used both, but they're not my tools of choice.

Comment: Totally understood.  Not trying to evangelize, but emacs is almost worth using on a Mac just because all of the text entry fields accept the basic emacs keyboard shortcuts out-of-the-box (e.g., ctrl+a goes to the beginning of the line, ctrl+k kills the line (except on StackOverflow where this shortcut has been hijacked to insert backticks))

Comment: Shame we only have a left control key!

Comment: I've remapped caps lock to ctrl.  It's fabulously comfortable :)

Comment: How does that help with, say, ctrl-a?

Comment: Pinky on caps, ring finger on a.  Does require a slight move of the wrist.  The remap can be done directly from system preferences -> keyboard -> modifier keys.  (Again, not trying to evangelize... it's a feature of OS X that not a ton of people know about.)